# Applying differentiation chain rule to sum of scalar valued vector functions with respect to a matrix

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, matrix-calculus, chain-rule

Assume I have set of matrix-vector equations that look like the following:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
x_{i,w} \\ 
y_{i,w} \\
z_{i,w}
\end{bmatrix} = a \left(\mathbf{^{w}T_{c}}\right)^{-1}\left(\mathbf{K}\right)^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix}
u_{i} \\ 
v_{i} \\
1
\end{bmatrix}$$

where $0 < i \leq n$, $a$ is a positive constant, $\mathbf{^{w}T_{c}}^{-1}$ is a $4 \times 4$ matrix, and $\mathbf{K}$ is a $4 \times 3$ matrix.

For each vector $\begin{bmatrix} x_{i,w} & y_{i,w} & z_{i,w} \end{bmatrix}^\top$, I have a scalar valued function $f_i$:

$$ f_i\left(\begin{bmatrix}
x_{i,w} \\ 
y_{i,w} \\
z_{i,w}
\end{bmatrix}\right) = s_i$$

The sum of all scalar valued functions is a scalar

$$ S = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}f_i $$

I would like to compute each of the scalar derivatives $\frac{\partial s_i}{\partial \mathbf{^{w}T_{c}}^{-1}}$ with respect to the matrix $\mathbf{^{w}T_{c}}^{-1}$ as well as the total derivative $\frac{S}{\partial \mathbf{^{w}T_{c}}^{-1}}$.

I think this requires the use of the chain rule, and I think that the derivative should have the same shape of $\mathbf{^{w} T_{c}}^{-1}$ but I am not sure.

Comment: What is $w$ in $x_{i,w}$?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo $w$ is just a coordinate frame label. $w$ = world coordinate frame.

Comment: The main problem with your question is that without specifying the scalar valued function the "solution" involves calculating (using @greg notation) the derivative of $a\mathbf{Y}\mathbf{b}$ which is fairly trivial (see "Matrix Algebra" by Abadir and Magnus).

Answer (score 0):

$
\def\a{\alpha}
\def\BR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{c}#1\end{array}\right]}
$Here is a partial answer.

For ease of typing, I'll drop your elaborate super/subscripts and define the variables
$$\eqalign{
Y = {\bf{^{w}T_{c}}}^{-1} \qquad 
\a = a \qquad b = K^{-1}\m{u_i\\v_i\\{\tt1}} \qquad 
c = \m{x_{i,w}\\y_{i,w}\\z_{i,w}} = \a\,Yb \\
}$$
Concentrate on a single component function $\BR{\phi(c) = f_i(x_i)}.\,$ Calculate its differential, change the independent variable from $c\to Y,\;$
then recover the desired gradient
$$\eqalign{
\p \phi &= \gradLR{\phi}{c}:\p c \\
 &= \gradLR{\phi}{c}:\LR{\a\;\p Y\,b} \\
 &= \a\gradLR{\phi}{c}b^T:\p Y \\
\c{\grad{\phi}{Y}} &\c{= \a\gradLR{\phi}{c}b^T} \\
}$$
where $(:)$ denotes the Frobenius product, which is a concise
notation for the trace
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \frob{A}^2 \qquad \{ {\rm Frobenius\;norm} \}\\
}$$

Comment: Thank you, could you expand on (1) what the full answer would be and (2) where the Frobenius product used as a derivative comes from? I'd like to mark this as the answer, but I'm a bit lost as to where you are sourcing this method. Thank you